# Throttling parallel computations

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

### The Question

I have a finite list of values:

```
values :: [A]
```

... and an expensive, but pure, function on those values:

```
expensiveFunction :: A -> Maybe B
```

How do I run that function on each value in parallel and only return the first `n` results that complete with a `Just` and stop computation of the unfinished results?

```
takeJustsPar :: (NFData b) => Int -> (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
takeJustsPar maxJusts f as = ???
```

### The Motivation

I know how I would do this using `Control.Concurrent`, but I wanted to experiment using Haskell's parallelism features.  Also, the (scant) literature I could find seems to indicate that Haskell's parallelism features make it cheaper to spawn parallel computations and adapt the workload among the number of capabilities.

Comment: @hammar Thanks for pointing out the obvious flaw in my question.  I updated the question to reflect the fact that the results are still ordered, but a simple `take` of the original list will not work since the criterion for inclusion in the output is the result of the computation (a `Just` if it succeeds and `Nothing` if it failed).

Comment: Ok, so the function you want is equivalent to `takeJusts maxJusts f = take maxJusts . catMaybes . map f` except it evaluates the `f` calls in parallel?

Comment: You probably also want to prioritize the earlier computations then, since those are more likely to make it into the result.

Comment: @hammar So perhaps I should just chunk the list and compute in parallel each chunk, then update the accumulator after each chunk to reflect how many result I still need and keep going if it's non-zero.  I think I can figure out the rest from here and answer my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I attempted two solutions.  The first uses the `Par` monad (i.e. `Control.Monad.Par`):

```
import Control.Monad.Par (Par, NFData)
import Control.Monad.Par.Combinator (parMap)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

takeJustsPar :: (NFData b) => Int -> Int -> (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Par [b]
takeJustsPar n chunkSize f as = go n (chunksOf chunkSize as) where
    go _ [] = return []
    go 0 _  = return []
    go numNeeded (chunk:chunks) = do
        evaluatedChunk <- parMap f chunk
        let results      = catMaybes evaluatedChunk
            numFound     = length results
            numRemaining = numNeeded - numFound
        fmap (results ++) $ go numRemaining chunks
```

The second attempt used `Control.Parallel.Strategies`:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

chunkPar :: (NFData a) => Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
chunkPar innerSize outerSize as
  = concat ((chunksOf innerSize as) `using` (parBuffer outerSize rdeepseq))
```

The latter one ended up being MUCH more composable, since I could just write:

```
take n $ catMaybes $ chunkPar 1000 10 $ map expensiveFunction xs
```

... rather than baking in the `take` and `catMaybes` behavior into the parallelism strategy.

The latter solution also gives nearly perfect utilization.  On the embarrassingly parallel problem I tested it on, it gave 99% utilization for 8 cores.  I didn't test the utilization of the `Par` monad because I was borrowing a colleague's computer and didn't want to waste their time when I was satisfied with the performance of `Control.Parallel.Strategies`.

So the answer is to use `Control.Parallel.Strategies`, which gives much more composable behavior and great multi-core utilization.